# How to installed cocos 2d in xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, templates, cocos2d-iphone

I have installed cocos2d templates in xcode 4 and its installed sucessfully..But When I am going to create new project then I am not able to see cocos 2d.

Please help me for this query
Thanks in advance